# Arithmetic sequence in coefficients of $(x+y)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-theorem

For which $n$ the second and third and fourth term's coefficients of binomial expansion's $(x+y)^n$ makes arithmetic sequence?

Comment: by considering pascal triangle we see that it is true for $n=7$ but I am seeking a simple proof.

Comment: Well, the $n^{\text{th}}$ row is $$ 1 \quad n/1! \quad n(n-1)/2! \quad n(n-1)(n-2)/3! \quad n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)/4! \quad \dots$$  Perhaps you see the pattern.  From this, you should be able to answer your own question by asking when the differences of adjacent entries are the same.

Answer (score 0):

From $2\dbinom n2=\dbinom n1+\dbinom n3$ we get
$$n(n-1)=n+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}6$$
Since $n\neq 0$,
$$6n-6=6+n^2-3n+2$$
$$n^2-9n+14=0$$
so $n=2$ or $n=7$. For $n=2$ we don't have a 'fourth term'. Thus, $n=7$.

Comment: Thanks, a lot. That is very good.